# Benfica badge or Benfica's badge

Tags: adjectives, possessives

Should I say: I kissed Benfica badge or I kissed Benfica's badge.

How are football teams' names used as adjectives?

Comment: Sorry but ELU is not a place to ask questions for help on writing/grammar. [Ell.se] might be a better fit, but even there you'll need to add _a lot_ more context, like who Benfica is and what is the situation. But very quickly... it's most likely not 'kissed Benfica badge' if Benfica is a person.

Comment: Sports and companies are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

SPORT FOOTBALL

> **Harry Kane challenges Piers Morgan to kiss Tottenham badge for charity**

[as this is a long headline, the article the before Tottenham is removed!]

[a headline in The Standard](https://www.standard.co.uk/sport/football/harry-kane-challenges-piers-morgan-to-kiss-tottenham-badge-for-charity-a3497766.html)

*That was back in March 2017, when Tottenham beat Arsenal and, by God, **they did it again yesterday: Tottenham 3, Kane made two goals and Son made one.**

In English, the name of the team precedes the word team.

[Pretty please, let's not get into the soccer/football thing. The Brits decide this as football in the UK is much more important (for now) than the game in the US, which, yes, is called soccer.]

Kiss the Benfica badge!

Use "the" for regular language, remove "the" for **long titles. Here, if this were a headline, it's short, so it can be  kept.**

Comment: But headlinese might allow '...kiss Benfica badge' right? (which the OP might be about, but we don't know).

Comment: Yes, Mitch. Sure. However, that is a very short headline, so the "the" could be kept.

Comment: This has been covered before, quite a few times, I believe, and your example uses headlinese. OP's rendering should include an article.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ah, yes, one can rain on any parade. I guess you didn't see the game yesterday? Or maybe you are an Arsenal fan? I say "the OP" myself. Let's just have some fun for once, shall we?